Unable to access services on my local network through Wireguard, using Caddy and Docker
Architecture

Problem
I want to be able to reach my services, hosted on my local network (192.168.1.0/24), through my domain (example.com). At this time, I can access the Wireguard UI service hosted on the VPS (wgui.example.com), but none of my services hosted on my local network.
Unless required, like for Vaultwarden, I would like to terminate tls at the VPS and communicate over http through the wireguard tunnel to the gateway machine.
Configuration
Wireguard
# VPS Wireguard Server wg0.conf

[Interface]
Address = 10.1.10.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = (Server PrivateKey)
MTU = 1450
PostUp = /opt/wireguard-ui/postup.sh
PreDown =
PostDown = /opt/wireguard-ui/postdown.sh
Table = auto

[Peer]
PublicKey = (Client PublicKey)
PresharedKey = (Client PSK)
AllowedIPs = 10.1.10.3/32
PersistentKeepalive = 15  

# Wireguard UI postup.sh

!/usr/bin/bash
# /opt/wireguard-ui/postup.sh
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
ufw route allow in on wg0 out on enp1s0
iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE

# Wireguard UI postdown.sh

#!/usr/bin/bash
# /opt/wireguard-ui/postdown.sh
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
ufw route delete allow in on wg0 out on enp1s0
iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE

# Gateway Wireguard Client wg0.conf

[Interface]
Address = 10.1.10.3/24
PrivateKey = (Client PrivateKey)
MTU = 1450

[Peer]
PublicKey = (Server PublicKey)
PresharedKey = (Client PSK)
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = 123.456.7.890:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 15

Caddy
# VPS Caddyfile

example.com {

    root * /usr/share/caddy

}

import sites-enabled/*

# VPS Caddy wgui config

wgui.example.com {
        reverse_proxy :5000

        handle_errors {
                respond "{err.status_code} {err.status_text}"
        }
}

www.wgui.example.com {
        redir https://wgui.example.com{uri}
}

# VPS Caddy pihole config

pihole.example.com {
    reverse_proxy 10.1.10.3
}

www.pihole.example.com {
    redir https://pihole.example.com{uri}
}

# Gateway Caddy pihole config

pihole.example.com {
    reverse_proxy 192.168.1.20:1010
}

Sysctl
# Gateway sysctl.conf

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

Troubleshooting
When I attempt to access pihole.example.com, I received a 403 Forbidden error.
Wireguard connection
# VPS wg show

interface: wg0
  public key: (Server PublicKey)
  private key: (hidden)
  listening port: 51820

peer: 59mOhf8SBmD3tZFDUescxXRu219NP2kkpBY92Bk/XHo=
  preshared key: (hidden)
  endpoint: (ClientPublicIP):7615
  allowed ips: 10.1.10.3/32
  latest handshake: 1 minute, 38 seconds ago
  transfer: 2.33 MiB received, 7.20 MiB sent
  persistent keepalive: every 15 seconds


IP Tables
# VPS iptables -L -n

hain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-before-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-reject-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ufw-track-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
ufw-user-forward  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
ufw-not-local  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:51820
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 /* 'dapp_OpenSSH' */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
ACCEPT     udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:443

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
LOG        all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination   

# Gateway iptables -L -n

hain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     1    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     0    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     1    --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Ping

I can ping 10.1.10.3 from the VPS machine.
I can ping 192.168.20 on the Gateway machine, but not from the VPS machine.

Curl
If I run curl -I http://192.168.1.20/admin on the Gateway machine, I get:
HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
Connection: close
Location: https://192.168.1.20/admin
Server: Caddy
Date: Mon, 25 Nov 2024 05:55:33 GMT

Can you please help me understand where I'm going wrong?

For one in your server conf you need to have 192.168.1.0/24 additionally in AllowedIPs= under the [Peer] section for the Pi.
Besides, your Pi also need to have IP forwarding enabled (sysctl) and allowed (firewall) correspondingly.
Last but not least, your LAN hosts need to have route that uses the Pi as the gateway for your VPN subnet (so like 10.1.10.0/24 via 192.168.1.10). Otherwise the Pi will need to masquerade / source NAT for the VPN subnet (so that traffics from that will look like originating from the Pi to the LAN hosts).
